# How to proxy_pass a stream HTTP request?

Tags: nginx, streaming, nginx-reverse-proxy

Here's my nginx configuration. My api from port 8080 is an http stream returned by an Express server. When I use `vite` to do the development and set up the proxy to 8080. The response text can be streamed to the browser. However, when I was using nginx to proxy_passing the api, it seemed nginx had buffered the stream response from the Express server before it returned to the browser. The nginx didn't stream it to the browser as expected. How to modify the config file to make it be able to return the stream for proxy_pass.

```
http {
    include mime.types;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name xxx.com;
        keepalive_timeout 70;
        ssl_certificate <crt-path>;
        ssl_certificate_key <key-path>;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers   HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        }

        location / {
            root /public;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```